# Strip trailing filename of a Url path

Tags: rust

I have a `Url` and I would like to get the path part but without the trailing file name. If the `Url` is `http://my.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext` then I would like to get `/dir1/dir2`.

I've tried all kinds of splitting (`let parts = url.path().split("/");`, etc.) and gathering and joining and the code is horrible and looks inefficient.

Comment: *Which* `Url` type are you using? There are many possible choices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a crate, it's useful to understand the domain that the crate focuses on. Resolving a relative path against an absolute URL is a pretty common case. For the [url crate](https://crates.io/crates/url), this is done with [`join`](https://docs.rs/url/2.1.0/url/struct.Url.html#method.join):

```
use url::Url; // 2.1.0

fn main() {
    let u = Url::parse("http://my.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext").unwrap();
    let u2 = u.join("./").unwrap();
    assert_eq!("/dir1/dir2/", u2.path());
}
```

You can also use [`path_segments_mut`](https://docs.rs/url/2.1.0/url/struct.Url.html#method.path_segments_mut):

```
use url::Url; // 2.1.0

fn main() {
    let mut u = Url::parse("http://my.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext").unwrap();
    u.path_segments_mut().unwrap().pop();
    assert_eq!("/dir1/dir2", u.path());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`rsplitn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.rsplitn)

```
extern crate url;

use url::Url;

fn shorten(url: &Url) -> Option<&str> {
    url.path().rsplitn(2, '/').skip(1).next()
}

fn main() {
    let url = Url::parse("http://my.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(shorten(&url), Some("/dir1/dir2"));
}
```

This is not as easy as calling one method, but this is at least efficient.

If you want to *change* the current url to do so, you can use [`Url::path_segments_mut`](https://docs.rs/url/1.6.0/url/struct.Url.html#method.path_segments_mut):

```
extern crate url;

use url::Url;

fn shorten(mut url: Url) -> Result<Url, ()> {
    url.path_segments_mut()?.pop();
    Ok(url)
}

fn main() {        
    let url = Url::parse("http://my.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(shorten(url).unwrap().path(), "/dir1/dir2");
}
```